# Jump discontinuity of a function and its analytic phase

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $f \in BV(0,1)$ with a jump discontinuity at $x = a\in(0,1)$. Let $f_h$ be its Hilbert transform and let $$f_A(x) = f(x) + i f_h(x)$$ Is it true that the function $$\phi(x) = \angle{f_A(x)}$$ also has a jump discontinuity at $x = a$?

Comment: reason for down vote?

Comment: what is $\angle$? is it $\arg$?

Comment: @robjohn : yes, it is same as argument of a complex number.

Comment: @robjohn : On these lines : http://math.stackexchange.com/a/66095/2987

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to tackle this problem is to write $f = g+h$, where $h$ is a piecewise linear function such that $h(0) = h(1) = 0$, chosen so that $g = f-h$ doesn't have a jump discontinuity at $x = a$.  Now presumably you have some results that ensure that $g_A$ doesn't have a jump discontinuity at $x = a$.  You should be able to compute $h_A$ explicitly, and at this point the answer should be easy to determine.

(If memory serves me correctly, $h_h(x)$ will probably converge to $\pm\infty$ at $x = a$, with the $\pm$ being different on either side.  If this is the case, then the jump discontinuity of $\text{arg}(f_A)$ will be $\pm \pi$.)

Added later: looking at the comments below, it seems like memory did not serve me correctly, and the blow up at $x=a$ occurs with the same sign around both sides.  In that case $\text{arg}(f_A)$ will be either $\pi/2$ or $-\pi/2$, with no jump at all, at $x=a$.

Comment: Oops - I think I just filled in the gaps for Rajesh D's proposed answer.  Well if my explanation helped, you can upvote me.  Otherwise thank Rajesh D for giving you a good hint.

Comment: (+1) the Hilbert transform may blow up logarithmically at a jump discontinuity, but the argument of $f_A$ cannot jump more than $\pi$.

Comment: @robjohn : I doubt if $f_h$ blows up with opposite sign on both sides of jump, my guess is blows up with same sign on both sides. So my question is whether $arg(f_A)$ even jumps?

Comment: @RajeshD: You are correct. $\mathrm{PV}\int_{-1}^x\frac1t\,\mathrm{d}t=-\log(|x|)$ and there is no change of sign.